# Lattice paths: how many points could we be on after k steps?

Tags: combinatorics

I am not trying to count the number of lattice paths, but rather the number of possible points I could be at after k steps along lattice paths to some point.
Suppose we are in n dimensions. We are taking paths from $(0,0,0, ... , 0)$ to some point $(a,b,c, ... ,n)$ by adding 1 to a single coordinate of our choosing at each step.
After k steps, how many points could we be at?
For instance, after one step we could be on n different points. I am not sure how to generalize to any number of steps. What is the correct amount of points we could be on?

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: It's the number of partitions of $k$ into at most $n$ parts. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Rather than *partitions*, I think "number of *compositions* of $k$ into $n$ non-negative parts"

Comment: @Henry you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after $k$ steps you have $a+b+c+\cdots+n=k$ with all of $a,b,c,\ldots,n$ being non-negative integers.

A simple stars and bars argument gives this number as ${k+n-1 \choose n-1}={k+n-1 \choose k}$